# How to call a public view function of a Solidity contract without a wallet connected (ethers.js)

Tags: ethers.js

I need fully anonymous access (even if no wallet is installed) to some functions of my Solidity contract with Ethers.js.

Normally I do the following for "write" functions:

```js
  const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(
    window.ethereum as ethers.providers.ExternalProvider
  )

  const contract = new ethers.Contract(
    contractAddress,
    Contract.abi,
    provider
  )


  const result = await contract.getSomeData()
```

But when users don't have a wallet connected, I can't use this approach because their `window.ethereum` is undefined.

I experimented with parameters of the `ethers.providers.Web3Provider()` with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution myself... I need to use `ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider()` instead of `ethers.providers.Web3Provider()` because it takes network url as a parameter and can work without a wallet connected.

```js
  const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider("network url or nothing if it's a local network")

  const contract = new ethers.Contract(
    contractAddress,
    Contract.abi,
    provider
  )

  const result = await contract.getSomeData()
```